# Call remote server through oracle apex

Tags: external, remote-access, oracle-apex-20.2

How to call external server or remote server from Oracle APEX using various restful services kindly let me know.

Thanks & Regards,
Yokes G

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to set up a Rest Data Source entry. I am using Oracle Apex 20.2.

eg called myRest

using Simple HTTP
Remote Server: Server name without https: include the endpoint
JSON Operation: GET
Parameters: the header parameters

It is very easy to copy and paste this from PostMan.

Then you can use the following type of code to access this REST service

```
declare
    l_params apex_exec.t_parameters;
begin
    apex_exec.add_parameter( l_params, 'content', 'hello david' );
    apex_exec.add_parameter( l_params, 'to', '123456' );

    apex_exec.execute_rest_source(
        'myRest',
        'GET',
        NULL,
        l_params );
end;
```

Note that I couldn't get the JSON to work properly using Rest Data Sources and  so I use make_rest_request instead as follows:

```
declare
    l_host      constant varchar2(200) := 'https://platform.xxx.com';
    l_host_path constant varchar2(200) := l_host || '/v1/message';

    l_clob           clob;
    l_body clob;

begin

    l_body := '{
      "messages": [
          {
              "channel": "xxx",
              "to": "123",
              "content": "Hello from APEX"
          }
      ]
    }';

    apex_web_service.g_request_headers(1).name := 'Content-Type';
    apex_web_service.g_request_headers(1).value := 'application/json'; 
    apex_web_service.g_request_headers(2).name := 'Authorization';
    apex_web_service.g_request_headers(2).value := 'yourkey'; 

    l_clob := apex_web_service.make_rest_request(
          p_url         => l_host_path,
          p_http_method => 'POST',
          p_body        => l_body);

  end;
```

This second method is nice as then everything is in one place and you don't need to reference the REST Data Sources.